# Can I continue using a NetworkStream after an exception due to a timeout?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, exception, tcpclient

When receiving data from a `NetworkStream`, I can configure the `stream.ReadTimeout`.
When no data has been received within the configured time, I get a `SocketException` with `ex.SocketErrorCode=SocketError.TimedOut`.

Can I continue using the stream after this exception, or is there a chance that some bytes get lost this way?

Example code:

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 2000))
using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
{
    stream.ReadTimeout = 5000;

    while (true)
    {
        int i;
        try
        {
            i = reader.Read();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            SocketError socketError = SocketError.Success;
            if (ex.InnerException is SocketException)
                socketError = ((SocketException)ex.InnerException).SocketErrorCode;

            if (socketError == SocketError.TimedOut)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("no data received for 5 seconds");
                continue;
            }
            else throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3575154/1997232).

Comment: @Sinatr I don't think the answer you linked is correct. The TcpClient does not get disconnected at all in my tests, it works just fine. I merely don't know whether this approach is safe, or whether bytes could potentially get lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't found any documentation of this on .NET side, but `NetworkStream.ReadTimeout` uses (on windows) [setsockopt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476(v=vs.85).aspx) native function, and in description of this function and it's various options it is clearly stated (in description of `SO_RCVTIMEO` and `SO_SNDTIMEO` error codes):

> If a send or receive operation times out on a socket, the socket state
>   is indeterminate, and should not be used; TCP sockets in this state
>   have a potential for data loss, since the operation could be canceled
>   at the same moment the operation was to be completed.